# Storing data from API inside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Some quite simple question for most of you I think..
I am trying to save some data that i get from an API URL request inside one of my functions...

This is my URL request (example):

```
import urllib.request 
urllib.request.urlopen("https://aaa.com/api").read()
```

Now lats say that the answer I get is "25", and I want to "send" that "25" to a functions that testing the results from the API:

```
def test_api(a):
    if (a <= 5):
       return ("not good..")
    elif (a == 25):
       return ("great...")
```

So how can I send "automatically" the result from my API to be the (a) inside my function?

(Some of my API's give me back only simple numbers (312,46.12,98..) but the others give me back more complicated data like json and other lists but I will handle with it later...)

Comment: What is your server returning? JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store the result in a variable and pass it to the method.

```
import urllib.request 
response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://aaa.com/api").read()  

def test_api(a):
    if isinstance(a, int):
        if (a <= 5):
           return ("not good..")
        elif (a == 25):
           return ("great...") 
    else :
        return "Opps...I was expecting an Integer" 

def type_conversion(val, to_type, default=None):
    try:
        return to_type(val)
    except ValueError:
        return default

# type_conversion('str', int) # returns None
# type_conversion('str', int, 0) # returns 0
print (test_api(type_conversion(response, int)))
```

Comment: Well after checking it, i can see that my API give me back some "string"..  this is the API request : https://blockchain.info/q/addressfirstseen/1aa5cmqmvQq8YQTEqcTmW7dfBNuFwgdCD . and the answer is : " b'1418394209' " ,its not just a number, it came with that 'b',I need just the number, how  can I separate them? tnx!

Comment: @Itsko that's because you are getting a STRING as response.
if you look at the python documentation " b' " character in the front states this: ```Bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater must be expressed with escapes.``` so try `print (test_api(int(response)))`

Comment: btw directly converting to int or any other type might throw `ValueError`. you can implement your own safe casting function. I have edited the code snippet.

Comment: Great, both of you helped me alot!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `urlopen()` returns an integer:

```
import urllib.request 
a = urllib.request.urlopen("https://aaa.com/api").read()  

def test_api(a):
    if (a <= 5):
       return ("not good..")
    elif (a = 25):
       return ("great...") 

test_api(a)
```

If not, you'll need to extract the specific value from the response, and make sure it's an integer (e.g. `test_api(int(a))`).